# InvalidValueError: myMap is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to include a map on my website but it keeps on giving me an error. When I try it on a plain page with just the code for the map and nothing else it works.

HTML :

```
    <!-- Contact/Area Container -->
<div class="w3-container" id="where" style="padding-bottom:32px;">
    <div class="w3-content" style="max-width:700px">
        <h5 class="w3-center w3-padding-48"><span class="w3-tag w3-wide">WHERE TO FIND US</span></h5>
        <p>Find us at some address at some place.</p>

        <div id="googleMap" class="w3-sepia" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

            <p><span class="w3-tag">FYI!</span> We offer full-service catering for any event, large or small. We understand your needs and we will cater the food to satisfy the biggest criteria of them all, both look and taste.</p>
            <p><strong>Reserve</strong> a table, ask for today's special or just send us a message:</p>
            <form action="/action_page.php" target="_blank">
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="Name"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="number" placeholder="How many people" required name="People"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="datetime-local" placeholder="Date and time" required name="date" value="2017-11-16T20:00"></p>
                <p><input class="w3-input w3-padding-16 w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message \ Special requirements" required name="Message"></p>
                <p><button class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button></p>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyLiQj3MnPbOp5SoMewKILkSPHHb0BQYQ&callback=myMap"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function myMap()
{
  myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798);
  var mapOptions= {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
  });
  marker.setMap(map);


}
```

Comment: is `myMap` defined before you load the google maps api?  i'm guessing it's not

Comment: @Mark_M it is the title of the post `InvalidValueError: myMap is not a function`

Comment: show the code where you actually call `myMap()`

Comment: @Julian Zahra: You have lost a `div`

Comment: my map is defined in a javascript file it is linked to it, just forgot to include the line of code in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are referring to your `myMap` function, before loading the file that defines it in the line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyLiQj3MnPbOp5SoMewKILkSPHHb0BQYQ&callback=myMap"></script>
```

That's why you keep getting `myMap is not defined`, because its file hasn't been read yet.

**Solution:**

Your scripts should be reversed, to include the `script.js` before referring  `myMap` function in the googgle maps link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"> </script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyLiQj3MnPbOp5SoMewKILkSPHHb0BQYQ&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned, make sure that the api is loaded after the myMaps function. If you are an external file with the myMap code, do it like this:

```
<script src="<pathtofilewithmyMapsfunction>"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyLiQj3MnPbOp5SoMewKILkSPHHb0BQYQ&callback=myMap"></script>
```

or if you have the script inline in your page:

```
<script>
function myMap()
{
  myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798);
  var mapOptions= {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:12, scrollwheel: false, draggable: false,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDyLiQj3MnPbOp5SoMewKILkSPHHb0BQYQ&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error in my angular application. To fix the issue, I removed the link and followed these easy steps to wire it up the Angular Way!

[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828946/103617)

Answer (score 0):

Load google Maps file after DOM content is loaded:

Javascript Version

```
function init(){
  var element = document.createElement("script");
  element.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY&callback=myMap";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",init,false);
```

jQuery Version

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR-KEY&callback=myMap');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the error in my angular application. To fix the issue, I removed the link and followed these easy steps to wire it up the Angular Way!

[Integrating Google Maps in Your Angular Application by Seth Gwartney](https://alligator.io/angular/angular-google-maps/)